# When would physical operator (e.g. LocalTableScanExec) show no SQL metrics in web UI?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-webui

Compare the following structured queries and their execution plans in web UI.

I use the same dataset for two different queries.

```
val names = Seq("Jacek").toDF("name")
```

The following basic query has no SQL metrics in web UI

```
names.show
```

[image]

Surprisingly the query has **number of output rows** metric.

```
names.count
```

[image]

Why?

Comment: @user8371915 Yes. As mentioned on Spark Developers List, LocalRelation does not execute on workers -> there is no event to be send to SparkListener -> No Metrics in Web UI

Comment: @T.Gawęda Not really (or at least partially correct) and hence the question. I would not say that _"LocalRelation does not execute on workers"_ as that would not explain why the other query does run on executors and leads to the SQL metric to be displayed.

Comment: Jacek, `LocalRelation is a leaf logical plan that allow functions like collect or take to be executed locally, i.e. without using Spark executors.` and Ryan has told, that in that case there is nothing posted to listener

Comment: `BroadcastExchangeExec`, `FileSourceScanExec` and `SubqueryExec` are also leaf logical plans and they do "announce" the SQL metrics. See [SQLMetrics.postDriverMetricUpdates](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/metric/SQLMetrics.scala#L185-L186).

Comment: It's the second part of the question - They announce, but LocalTableScan does not. You can create a PR to invoke postDriverMetricUpdates